# How to Change url format using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need your help I am trying to change my URL format but I cannot do that I keep getting `Object Not Found` error.

Real URL is : http://localhost/website/page.php?pid=about

I want like this url using htaccess http://localhost/website/about.php

My code is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(([a-zA-z0-9\_\-\+]+))\.html|([a-zA-z0-9\_\-]+)\.php$ page.php?pptype=$2&pppage=$3&id=$4 [QSA,NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess clean URL's what's the best way to do it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661287/htaccess-clean-urls-whats-the-best-way-to-do-it)

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this for your url similar to `http://localhost/website/about.php`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewrwiteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+).php$ $1/page.php?pid=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Again i am  facing same problem object not found.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^website/([^/]*)\.php$ /website/page.php?pid=$1 [L]
```

It will leave you with the URL: `http://localhost/website/about.php`