# Hide comma and id in url with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My url is like:

```
domain.com/subpage-name,15
```

where integer after comma id page id.
I'd like to hide rest of url after subpage-name with .htaccess.

It's Zend Framework 1.12.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess clean URL's what's the best way to do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661287/htaccess-clean-urls-whats-the-best-way-to-do-it)

Comment: So you want to hide the information in a URL, which you use to decide which page to show, from the user? Let me be blunt: You can't. There would be no id for you to use, if you could. However, if the id is not important, you could leave it out altogether.